# Extract value from html select tag using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am getting whole select tag as a value from my code, in order to do work around the value i need to extract the value from my select tag,as this tag is dynamically created by the code.

Below is the value i am getting. How can i extract this using java script.Thanks for your help.

```html
   rowId[0].QValue = "<select id="Type112" class="GridList" rownumber="0" value="Q1 Only" ><option></option><option value="1" selected="selected">Q1 Only</option><option value="2">Q2 Only</option></select>"
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('Type112').value;` should do!

Comment: @Rayon - As this id is dynamically generating, have tried but didnt find a way to gt that id.

Comment: @Virat What do you mean by dynamically generated? Is this generated due to user input? During rendering of you webpage?

Comment: `As this id is dynamically generating` not in the code you posted. Perhaps, seeing as the code you posted isn't valid javascript, you could help us help you by showing the code involved - `Below is the value i am getting` how are you getting this? And how is the code you posted related to **valid** javascript code?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1085801/6320039

Comment: @jaromanda - As the above value is getting form a jqGrid by getRowData. I would like to extract the above text(let consider the whole value as text) by using javascript. As my jqGrid have a dropdown, thats why i am getting the diff value

Comment: As you have posted no javascript code, I have no idea what you're talking about ... drops mic ... I'm out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to do this would be to select the element from the DOM with one of the selection functions. In this case, I prefer `document.querySelector`:

```
var type112 = document.querySelector('#type112');
```

The `#` means 'id', and you can pass any combination of valid CSS to `document.querySelector`.

Then, to produce the value of this element, simply call

```
type112.value
```

This will give you the text value of the currently selected `option` within the `select` element.

Based on your comment, I'm sensing that perhaps you have the text of an element and want to parse out the id? If that's the case, you can try:

```
var elemString = // whatever your str is
var id = (elemString.match(/id="([^"]+)"/) || [])[0];
```

This assumes that the id is the first attribute in the string, as well as a whole litany of other things that will probably break in production but will work in the absence of a coherent understanding of what you're trying to do.

Comment: OP asked for **value**, you are returning the element

Comment: Even this Id is generating dynamically, for different values have diff ids. Is there any way to split the code and extract value?

Comment: @Virat Updated the answer. Are you saying that you have a string, or that you have an `HTMLElement`?

Comment: @furkle I have mentioned the value as "rowId[0].QValue = <select". It is a string type. sorry for not displayed clearly. The value should be like this  rowId[0].QValue = "<select......./>"

Comment: @furkle, the same way can i get the value, like your answer parse out the id?

Comment: @frukle Got it 
var elemString = // whatever your str is
var id = (elemString.match(/value="([^"]+)"/) || [])[0];- Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the select element id to retrieve the value of the element.

```html
   <select id="Type112" class="GridList" rownumber="0" value="Q1 Only" ><option></option><option value="1" selected="selected">Q1 Only</option><option value="2">Q2 Only</option></select>
```

You can write the javascript to get the element by id `Type112`
and so on to get the value:

```
var s = document.getElementById("Type112");
var selNum = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
alert(selNum);
```

Here's a [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/anistark/5fe2juvn)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
var list = document.getElementById("Type112");
console.log(list.value)
```

```html
<select id="Type112" class="GridList" rownumber="0" value="Q1 Only" ><option></option><option value="1" selected="selected">Q1 Only</option><option value="2">Q2 Only</option></select>
```